# C Operator priority at CLA certification exam

Tags: c, operator-keyword

Currently, I'm taking C language certification course at cppinstitute.org.
In one of it's quizzes there is a question as below to recognize output.

```
int i = 1,j= 1;
int w1,w2;
w1 = (i>0) && (j<0) || (i<0) &&(j>0);
w2 = (i<=0) || (j>=0) && (i>=0) || (j<=0);
printf("%d",w1 == w2);
```

I think the program should print 0 to the screen, but the quiz accepts printing 1 as the answer.

Am I correct?if not ,where I'm wrong?
Thanks in advance!I'm a beginner.

Comment: Since you've not explained how you came up with 0, we can't tell what you assumed wrong, can we?

Comment: `0` seems correct to me. Maybe there is a mistake in the quiz, or the quiz is not the same as what you have posted here

Comment: It is a shame nobody has written any software to print what C code should print according to the C standard. If only we had some way of, say, simulating the execution of C code, then we could figure out the answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I've heard some clever people use gadgets called 'compilers' — have you heard of anyone using one of them successfully? :D  My default compiler options give errors (warnings if you aren't as fussy as me), about `error: suggest parentheses around ‘&&’ within ‘||’ [-Werror=parentheses]
 w1 = (i>0) && (j<0) || (i<0) &&(j>0);` and `error: suggest parentheses around ‘&&’ within ‘||’ [-Werror=parentheses]
 w2 = (i<=0) || (j>=0) && (i>=0) || (j<=0);`.  Fix the first and it diagnoses the same problem on the second part of the line.  That's GCC 7.2.0.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I think that is just a rumor. I tried using a compiler once, and it only gave me some unreadable object module, not an answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: yeah, I've noticed that I can't read the output from a compiler either.  There must be a reason for them, but …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, `&&` higher precedence than `||` operator.

So,

```
w1 = (i>0) && (j<0) || (i<0) &&(j>0);   
   = 1 && 0 || 0 && 1;   
   = 0 || 0  
   = 0
```

And

```
w2 = (i<=0) || (j>=0) && (i>=0) || (j<=0);
   = 0 || 1 && 1 || 0
   = 0 || 1 || 0
   = 1 || 0
   = 1
```

So, `w1 == w2` become false. So, correct output is 0.

Comment: The `(j > 0)` at the end of evaluating `w1` is not evaluated because of short-circuit rules.  The `(i < 0)` is false so the value from `&& (j > 0)` has no effect on the result (it's false) and it is not evaluated.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The standard defines the result of the `&&` and `||` or operators in terms of both its operands, so using the values of both operands is a valid logical deduction for determining the value of the result. The shortcut rule is stated only after that definition, and the fact that the second operand is not evaluated if not needed is relevant only to determining whether or not side effects occur; it has no consequence to the primary effect.